# rspec controller test, get with multiple parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to test to a controller that works on browser and looks like this

```
http://url.dev/jobs/1445.json?project_id=1144&accesskey=MyString
```

this is what i have on my controler spec file:

```
params = {:id=>"1445", :project_id=>1144, :accesskey=>"MyString"}
get :show, params, format: :json
```

On the log i see:

```
Processing by JobsController#show as HTML
    Parameters: {"id"=>"1440"}
```

Why it is trying to process as HTML and not as JSON? Why it only receives the id parameter?

Also, if I do this:

```
get :show, id: params[:id], format: :json
```

It tries to process using JSON but it dont works because I need the other params.

Answer (score 12):

The `format: :json` part must be on the 2nd argument.

This works pretty well

```
params = {:id=>"1445", :project_id=>1144, :accesskey=>"MyString", format: :json}
get :show, params
```

Answer (score -2):

`get` only takes **2** arguments, the "action" and "args"

Your code:

```
get :show, params, format: :json
```

Is passing in **3**